# Terraform AWS EC2 instance - Ubuntu error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to launch an EC2 instance within Terraform. I'm following a 2 years ago tutorial and I get an error when trying to run terraform apply: "creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: The architecture 'i386,x86_64' of the specified instance type does not match the architecture 'arm64' of the specified AMI. Specify an instance type and an AMI that have matching architectures, and try again. You can use 'describe-instance-types' or 'describe-images' to discover the architecture of the instance type or AMI."
My code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "...//key"
  secret_key = "...//key"
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-first-server" {
  ami           = "ami-007855ac798b5175e"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

I'm really new to Cloud/terraform and I have no idea what is the issue. I copied from AWS the provided AMI for 64-bit (x86).

Comment: Are you confident that this is your real code that you are using?

Comment: Yes, this is the only code. It's a freecodecamp tutorial.

Comment: Any specific link to that "freecodecamp tutorial"? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLB_c_ayRMo From 30 minute -> 42 minute.

Comment: You are using the wrong AMI id. The one you are using is for ARM

Comment: @CarlosB The Ami is not for arm. Please check in aws and you will find that Ami is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely **nothing wrong** with your code. I just deployed your code in `us-east-1` and everything works exactly as expected. Thus your issue is likely to be caused by other factors, e.g. other code version which you use, which is not provided in the question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try to look over to find out which can be the issue.